# How to calculate 1040ES tax payments for 2018?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

My first quarterly 2018 1040ES payment is due in April. As I have no regular withholding payments being made (being retired),I have to make quarterly payments to cover Federal income tax.

I thought this would be rather simple, use last year's AGI, take standard deduction, eliminate the personal exemption, then apply the new tax brackets.
I was astounded to find that my tax liability had increased almost 50% from this past year (2017)!

Is there something that I'm missing in my process, how do other people calculate these quarterly payments?

BTW, TurboTax - for the very first time in years -- did not produce the 1040ES vouchers for the Fed (but did for State & Local).

Comment: It's not obvious from the info provided what went wrong if anything, but I'm not aware of any way a retiree could face a 50% tax increase given the same level of income.

Comment: @Hart CO, "sharpened my pencil" and your partially correct, the increased tax liability is only 22%.

Comment: That still seems really high, I've seen mostly reductions, and at the very high end of income a slight increase.

Comment: @Hart CO, the explanation is this:   Consider the following: (1) same income level 2017 to 2018, BUT (2) reduction to deductions from 36K to 24K (largely due to SALT and other "reforms"), (3) elimination of 8.1K in personal exemptions creates a situation where the **taxable income** increases about 20K.  That shift of 20K, in combination with change in tax brackets from 2017 to 2018, creates ~22% increase in tax burden.

Comment: in response to your "very high end of income", we are talking about initial taxable incomes less than 100K. I'm not sure that qualifies as "high end".  I just found a neat calculator at https://www.taxact.com/tools/tax-bracket-calculator that seems to verify my BOE calculations.

Comment: Ah, yeah I was foolishly thinking in the context of my state, where taxes are relatively low, so wasn't thinking about SALT change having such an incredible impact.

Comment: It's hard to say whether you're missing something without more details.  Note though that the ["safe harbor" provisions](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p505#en_US_2017_publink1000194564) shield you from penalties as long as you pay at least as much as you paid in taxes last year (or 110% of last year's taxes in some circumstances).  So even if your tax increases dramatically, you won't be penalized as long as you pay at least as much as you did last year.  (As far as I know these provisions were not  altered by the new law.)